# Whats difference between Complex event processing (i.e Progress Apama) framework and C#?

Tags: c#, events, apama

I  work in a financial sector, there is a product in our organisation that is mainly built for monitoring various trading events so to generate alerts. The product is developed in C# but for tracking and raising meaningful events/alerts another module of the system is developed in Progress's Apama. Since i don't know about the product much, my doubt is why another framework is needed for the Event & alert processing. Kindly guide.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider first stating with "basic web research".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use C# and not assembler? Because it's a higher level abstraction that allows you to do the same things more quickly and with fewer errors.

You would use a CEP product like Apama for the same reason. It's designed to make even driven programming quicker and easier than using other technologies.